# action mailer and rails 4 methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have been following quite an old tutorial in order to create a contact form and then create a mailer that sends to the site admin. I am running into some problems i think because i am on rails 4.1.1 and the tutorial is so old! I was wondering if anyone could give me some guidance-i am learning rails. The error i am currently getting is as follows 
NoMethodError in MessagesController#create
undefined method `deliver_message' for ContactMailer:Class

here is my code

messages controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /messages
  # GET /messages.json
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  # GET /messages/1
  # GET /messages/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /messages/new
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  # GET /messages/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /messages
  # POST /messages.json
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        ContactMailer.deliver_message(@message)
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.update(message_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /messages/1
  # DELETE /messages/1.json
  def destroy
    @message.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :company, :phone, :subject, :body)
    end
end
```

development.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smpt.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: 'your_email_username',
    password: 'your_email_password'
  }

  CONTACT_RECIPIENT = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Required for Devise gem
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

end
```

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.contact_mailer.message.subject
  #

    def message(message)
    subject    message.subject
    body       :message => message
    recipients CONTACT_RECIPIENT
    from       message.email
    sent_on    Time.now
    end

  end
end
```

having then changed def message to def deliver_message(message) i then get the following error

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#create
undefined method `subject' for #<ContactMailer:0x007fdb5d7e0028>
  subject    message.subject
```

Comment: please add view form in the next question (it will help to find the answer)

Comment: ok, don't know if you are creating the new question, but the problem is that your model Message doesn't have subject column. In order to overcome this problem you should firstly create migration, secondly, add :subject to permit_params method and, lastly, add subject field to message form (views/messages/new)

Comment: Just for my own knowledge is this because of it now being Rails 4? I just wondered why this is the case...

Comment: no, it's either the tutorial is inconsistent or you've missed something from it

Comment: This is confusing me though because the form which is rendered from messages/new and the message model all have a subject field!?

Comment: ok,     subject    message.subject
    body       :message => message
    recipients CONTACT_RECIPIENT
    from       message.email
    sent_on    Time.now should be     subject:    message.subject
    body:       :message => message
    recipients: CONTACT_RECIPIENT
    from:       message.email
    sent_on:    Time.now

Comment: note colons after subject: and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is as simple as changing

```
def message(message)
end
```

to

```
def deliver_message(message)
end
```

Comment: Thanks sorry that seems so obvious! Having updated that i am now getting another error so i have updated the question in case this can too be resolved!

Comment: I'm afraid the rules of the forum are so, that if you've got the answer, and new question appears - you have to create new question..

Comment: Thanks, i will do but obviously i have to wait 90 minutes so hopefully i can resolve it in the meantime!

Comment: I just saw your previous comment! Thanks so much for the guidance it is most appreciative! If im still struggling in 90 minutes i will post another question but i am hoping with your comments i can get there myself! Thanks!